# Custom where clauses in PHP prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm reading about PDO and prepared statement, focused in Postgres.

As I understood how ps is implemented in PHP, I can register a named query, then define variables for it and run it multiple times. But what happens when the use of where clauses depend on parameters.

For exemple, if `!empty($param3)` then I add a where clause, but if it is empty that clause won't be used in the query.

The best situation for this is a filter form to narrow a list of records: if no filter is used the query won't even use WHERE, while all filters may be used resulting in a big WHERE query.

As I see now, I'd need to register 1 prepared statement for each situation, but that would result in lots of statements to maintain and test separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't prepare queries you aren't going to execute.

It's true that you need to prepare a different SQL string if you have differences in the search terms in the WHERE clause.

Prepared queries allow you to use parameters in place of literal values only; that is, where you would normally put a quoted string or date, or a numeric literal.  But parameters cannot be used for other syntax, like table names, column names, SQL expresions, SQL keywords, etc.

So you must create the SQL string *before* preparing it, depending on application conditions like `!empty($param3)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use prepared statements, register 1 prepared statement for each situation.

Comment: another option would be `$select_query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";` and add `$select_query .= " WHERE param='value'";`